# How to reject incoming call programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, callkit

I'm having a VoIP app in which calling works normally.

However, when we have an active VoIP call and the user receives a normal PSTN call, the active VoIP call goes blank - no audio is audible on either side.

To resolve this issue, we decided to end the new incoming call programmatically and I'm successfully able to detect an incoming PSTN call. But when I try to end the call, I get error saying:

```
EndCallAction transaction request failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction error 4.)
```

Error code 4 refers to `CXErrorCodeRequestTransactionErrorUnknownCallUUID`.

Below is my code:

```
// called during initialization
self.callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
[self.callObserver setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

```
- (void)callObserver:(nonnull CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(nonnull CXCall *)call {
    // isCallInProgress static variable tracks if a VoIP call is active and I verified its value - works as expected
    if(isCallInProgress) {
        if(!call.isOutgoing && !call.hasConnected && !call.hasEnded) {
            NSLog(@"*** New incoming call detected while a call is in progress - so reject it");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                CXEndCallAction *endCallAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:call.UUID];
                CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:endCallAction];

                CXCallController *controller = [[CXCallController alloc] init];
                [controller requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"*** EndCallAction transaction request failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                    else {
                        NSLog(@"*** EndCallAction transaction request successful");
                    }
                }];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: I would expect this to be impossible by design. Apple very rarely allows apps to mess with calls they don't directly control. I'd dig into why your VoIP call doesn't behave correctly when a PSTN call comes in and try to fix that instead. Make sure you're properly responding to audio interruptions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/#3730350

Comment: Yes, it is not your app's job to decide if an incoming call should be rejected.  The user should see a screen that asks them what to do. If they reject the call, ios will handle it. If they choose to end your call and accept the incoming call then ios will send the appropriate event to your app.  Is your app using CallKit correctly so that iOS is aware that a VoIP call is in progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting the solution which I decided to go ahead with and which solved the problem for us.

I decided to listen for the AudioSession interruption which are triggered by the system based on what's happening with the device:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleInterruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];
```

Following piece of code is specific to Twilio which solved the current call going blank while a new incoming call is ringing:

```
- (void)handleInterruption:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification]) {
        if ([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan]]) {
            self.audioDevice.block();
    }
}
```